# UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT Ionic 4, request failure with http statusCode:401,exception: , system error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:
paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"8c7aba64efbc"}
paypal.sdk: UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT

Comment: You are using sandbox or live credential?

Comment: i am using live credential

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: this.payPal.init({
    PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'AS6N9cSOc_qn-BEFsqHLDRmiRDdT4QiVEzmJLL3V6eK8Fe2So4SAPhfVHmSNpfU77rhNT1YRLoWQKv6_',
    PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID'
  }).then(() => {
   PayPalEnvironmentProduction
    this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentProduction', new PayPalConfiguration({
    })).then(() => {
      let payment = new PayPalPayment(this.agentAmount, this.currency, 'Description', 'sale');
      this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((res) => {
     
      }, () => {
      });
    },